# What are the guidelines for using public datasets for publication?

Tags: data, online-resource

Data are available publicly on several websites e.g. icpsr, databank, UK Data Archive. I am seeking guidelines, references and examples about using these open data for research. In other words, I want to publish a paper based on analyzing some publicly available datasets. Do I need permission first or they are available actually for me to use them in my research ?

Comment: There are far too many public data sources to list, but I bet many of them have citation instructions available.  For ICPSR, for example: https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/content/shared/ICPSR/faqs/why-and-how-should-i-cite-data.html

Comment: This recent article seems relevant http://www.nature.com/news/legal-confusion-threatens-to-slow-data-science-1.20359

Answer (score 7):

A public data set is just that: public.  They have been made available for the specific purpose of being used by other people.

Thus, you generally do not need permission, but you *will* need to appropriately cite the source of the dataset, thereby giving appropriate credit to its originators.  For a well-curated collection, you can find appropriate citation information embedded within either the "packaging" or metadata of the dataset or at the online source where you obtain it.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to speak in generalities: each database will be different.

Databases normally will have some sort of usage agreement associated with them. For example, [DrugBank](http://www.drugbank.ca/) posts the following prominently on their front page:

> DrugBank is offered to the public as a freely available resource. Use
>   and re-distribution of the data, in whole or in part, for commercial
>   purposes (including internal use) requires a license. We ask that
>   users who download significant portions of the database cite the
>   DrugBank paper in any resulting publications.

Other databases may not be as up-front about the limitations. Instead, they may have a usage page accessible somewhere on their website. (Usually there's a link in the header or footer.) For example, the NCBI provides their usage disclaimer at the bottom of each page, under a [Polices and Guidelines](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/home/about/policies.shtml) link. Likewise, the UK Data Archive provides guidance under a [Terms and Conditions](http://www.data-archive.ac.uk/conditions/) link at the bottom of the website.

Other resources may have limitations that apply per-dataset. ICPSR looks to be of this type. If you download the "Codebook" for each dataset, near the front there should be a "Terms of Use Statement", which may just be a link to a page. Here's the one for the [2010 US Census Data](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/34753/terms), most of which is limitations on redistributing the data. But other may have requirements regarding publishing and citation.

---

If I had to summarize, though, public data repositories are generally fine with you publishing academic work which makes use of their data - that's why they're providing it in the first place! Conditions on publishing, when present, are generally involved with to requiring appropriate citation, or things like not trying to de-anonymize personal data (both of which you should be adhering to anyway). The non-trivial usage restrictions tend to revolve more around redistribution of the data sets, either by as-is or in processed forms.

That said, you can't make any general statements about usage - each database will have it's own terms and conditions, most of which should be easily available from the same location you obtain the data.